# 'FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

I already installed the latest version of [phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

But when i build the project, I got the error message below.
I tried many solutions mentioned at stackoverflow and other websites with no positive result.

```
com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookConnectPlugin.m:11:
Et3arrafApp/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookConnectPlugin.h:11:9: fatal error:
      'FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
        ^
1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/Et3arrafApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Et3arrafApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/FacebookConnectPlugin.o Et3arrafApp/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookConnectPlugin.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error: /Users/apple/Desktop/et3arraf/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 65
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

Comment: In fact, I got a fresh files from the server and installed the plugin via cordova CLI. and everything gonna fine.

Comment: We got it to work using by downloading https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin and using plugman to install.

Comment: I got it working when installing the plugin from a local copy. https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin#-----cordova-registry-warning-ios

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I encountered the same problem today.

Installing this plugin using the plugin register does not work (for iOS) at the moment.

You must clone the repository (`phonegap-facebook-plugin`) to your local file system, say `$HOME/src/phonegap-facebook-plugin`.  And then install the plugin pointing to that path, e.g. `cordova plugin add $HOME/src/phonegap-facebook-plugin
 ...`

It turns out that `FacebookSDK.framework` isn't installed properly when fetching through the plugin registry.  It should look like this:

```
$ ls -l plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/platforms/ios/FacebookSDK.framework/
total 24
lrwx------  1 mjl  staff   24 Aug 15 15:23 FacebookSDK -> ./Versions/A/FacebookSDK
lrwx------  1 mjl  staff   20 Aug 15 15:23 Headers -> ./Versions/A/Headers
lrwx------  1 mjl  staff   22 Aug 15 15:23 Resources -> ./Versions/A/Resources
drwx------  4 mjl  staff  136 Aug 15 15:23 Versions
```

But the symlinks aren't preserved when installing through the plugin registry... They are preserved when installing from the local file system though.

Answer (score 1):

I had solved it by installing the plugin using `--save` option.

in my case I had downloaded the plugin to my computer and what I did is :

```
cordova plugin add --save <my downloaded plugin directory> --variable APP_ID=<app_id> --variable APP_NAME=<app_name>
```

The required file will be listed same as @mjl's result from `ls -l plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/platforms/ios/FacebookSDK.framework/`

P/S: if you are using iTerm, you can drag the folder into your iTerm terminal and the full directory path will be type in automatically.

Answer (score -2):

After more and more search around the web, I tried to re create the sym link of Headers, FacebookSDK and Resources and resolved

ln -s ./Versions/A/Headers Headers

and so on